# массив 6X4. определить разность между min и max элемент в каждой строке

Tags: c#, массивы

Помогите советом. Написал программу, но не знаю как должен продолжить.

Массив 6x4, заполнил рандомом, а дальше не понимаю что делать.

```cs
int[,] a = new int[6, 4];

Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        a[i, j] = random.Next(100);
        Console.Write("{0,5}", a[i, j]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Ну например, пройти циклом по массиву. Для каждой строки при помощи Linq найти  min и max элемент, найти их разность, вывести в консоль. Все. Да и желательно код вставлять текстом, если даже кто то захочет вам помочь и ему нужно будет воспроизвести ваш код, ему придется его набирать.

Comment: Спасибо , но ничего не понятно

Comment: Ну вы просили совет. Я описал самый простой и вполне рабочий способ. А вы как то пробовали это решить ?

Comment: @PavelPopov непросто подружить многомерный массив и Linq, даже мне.

Comment: @aepot Согласен, через linq не самый простой способ. Я сам погуглил и это заняло минут 3-5.  return (from col in Enumerable.Range(0, arr.GetLength(1)) select arr[rowIndex, col]).Max();  Но красивый )  Но вот вы мне скажите стоило все решить за человека, который по сути сам почти ничего не попытался сделать ? мне просто тут за это не раз делали упреки и я вот немного не понимаю

Comment: `foreach (int n in arr)` - работает с многомерным массивом.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `arr.Cast<int>.Select(...)` тоже :) Только к построчным вычислениям это не совсем применимо.

Comment: @PavelPopov по поводу халявы, здесь я хотя-бы в конечном итоге нормально оформленный вопрос увидел, вот если бы в нем была только первая строчка и больше ничего, ответа гарантированно бы не по следовало. SO с учебными заведениями договор о готовых решениях не подписывал, все в рамках здравого смысла. На меня тоже мог кто-нибудь придти, напасть с претензиями и заминусовать, каждый вправе делать здесть то, что считает нужным (в рамках общих правил). Ну а то что человек сам не захотел разбираться - это его трудности. Чем дальше обучение, тем сложнее вникать. На готовых решениях далеко не уедешь.

Comment: @PavelPopov Каждый участник сам для себя находит в чём ему интерес отвечать здесь, каждый сам находит и кому помогать, а кому нет. У меня общего решения нет, бывало, что отвечал спустя такое время когда заведомо уже прошла пора сдать домашку, бывало вопрос интересный был хотелось ответить (или просто показать что я в эту тему умею). В целом же -- я не хотел бы, чтобы меня лечил такой врач или я пользовался софтом, который напишет вот такой "программист".

Comment: @aepot Спасибо!

Comment: @AK Спасибо! я с вами согласен)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если по-простому, то начать с первого элемента в каждой строке, далее каждый последующий элемент сравнивать отдельно с минимумом и с максимумом, и обновлять минимум и максимум, если меньше или больше.

```cs
int[,] a = new int[6, 4];

Random random = new Random();
// лучше использовать реальный размер массива, потому что если поменяете размер массива,
// вам придется править код сразу в нескольких местах, а это неудобно
for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < a.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        a[i, j] = random.Next(100);
        Console.Write("{0,3}", a[i, j]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    int min = a[i, 0];
    int max = a[i, 0];
    for (int j = 1; j < a.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        if (a[i, j] < min)
            min = a[i, j];
        if (a[i, j] > max)
            max = a[i, j];
    }
    Console.WriteLine(max - min);
}
```

Вывод в консоль.

```
 23 63 47 32
 51 79 36 23
 82 40 60  8
 69 92 22 91
 92 91 86 18
 26 47 70 23
40
56
74
70
74
47
```

---

Ради развлечения, вот Linq вариант

```cs
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable.Range(0, a.GetLength(0)).Select(i => 
    Enumerable.Range(0, a.GetLength(1)).Select(j => a[i, j]).Max() - 
    Enumerable.Range(0, a.GetLength(1)).Select(j => a[i, j]).Min()
)));
```